# Why shake event not working in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I added shake gesture plugin for my project.

**This is my code:**

```
<button onclick="myFunc()" id="round">Gesture Call</buttom>
    <script>

        function myFunction()
        {
            window.open("emcall.html");
            navigator.vibrate([2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000]);
            navigator.notification.beep(10);

        }
        function myFunc()
        {
            alert('shake working');
            function onShake()
            {
                alert("shake success");
                window.open("emcall.html");

            }

            function onError()
            {
                alert("errorq");

            }
            shake.startWatch(onShake,30,onError);


        }

    </script>
```

Some thing wrong in mycode help me to over come this.

Comment: Have you download the shake plugin?

Comment: @e4en yeah downloded through cli

Comment: What system is it not working on? Have you tried on others?

Comment: @ste2425 i tried with my mobile but not works

Comment: @KishoreKumar Included cordova.js and added deviceready event?

Comment: @Gandhi bro device ready event not added bro ,i didn't added anyplatform still now so cordova.js file is not there bro

Comment: @KishoreKumar Then how did you manage to test it on device?

Comment: through phonegap app bro @Gandhi i installed it on myandroid device if i enter the ip address of my system then it will run .

Comment: @KishoreKumar i doubt that it could work without cordova.js and deviceready event. Console errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114113/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-gandhi).

Comment: @Gandhi you are correct with out adding platform and testing it not working

Comment: @KishoreKumar it works now?

Comment: @Gandhi yes bro bro do you know how to update platform

Comment: @KishoreKumar Did you added codova.js and deviceready event?

Comment: @Gandhi yes bro cordova.js added and device event read also added

Comment: @KishoreKumar Then will post the same in answer? Mentioning that it should be tested in device. Is that fine?

Comment: @Gandhi yes bro working fine

Comment: @KishoreKumar Posted the answer. Please do accept so that it can be helpful for other too

Answer (score 3):

Include `cordova.js` file in your HTML file and register deviceready event in your script. Then, invoke shake plugin related code inside deviceready event listener function. It should work.

Also ensure to test it on device after adding and building platform as i dont see this shake plugin supported in browser.

Comment: bro thanks i was upvoted your answer because of you and one more member are reason to find the solution

Comment: @KishoreKumar No issue bro.

Answer (score 0):

->Plugin not supporting in phonegap.app,who are all testing the app using you ip address on phonegap app.

->just add platform through cli.

->And build or run it and test .